# CiviDiscount for Initial "New" Member

Tags: wordpress, civimember, cividiscount

Our organization pro-rates dues based on the join date. CiviDiscount can handle this (albeit a bit manual in terms of changing dates) through an automatic code based on 'member status' -- but the problem is those who are joining don't yet have a 'member status' of 'new'. How can this be configured so someone who is completing the application for the first time can't receive a discount we'd like everyone to get *except* members (in terms of renewal).